# R Aggregate days and count specific observations for each day

Tags: r, date, aggregate, grouping

```
         Day    Time                               Numbers
  6388 2017-02-01   10:43                               R33
7129 2017-02-04   15:32               N39.0, N39.0, N39.0
9689 2017-02-17   08:54    S72.11, S72.11, S72.11, S72.11
6703 2017-02-02   18:55                               R11
9026 2017-02-13   17:34               S06.0, S06.0, S06.0
5013 2017-01-25   00:33        J18.1, J18.1, J18.1, J18.1
5849 2017-01-29   17:57               I21.4, I21.4, I21.4
9245 2017-02-14   19:03               J18.0, J18.0, J18.0
1978 2017-01-09   21:23                             K59.0
5021 2017-01-25   02:46               I47.1, I47.1, I47.1
9258 2017-02-14   20:19                             S42.3
541  2017-01-03   11:44               I63.8, I63.8, I63.8
4207 2017-01-20   19:52            E83.58, E83.58, E83.58
8650 2017-02-11   18:39       R55, R55, S06.0, S06.0, R55
9442 2017-02-15   21:30                             K86.1
4186 2017-01-20   18:27                             S05.1
4231 2017-01-20   22:10                             M17.9
6847 2017-02-03   11:45                             L02.4
1739 2017-01-08   21:19                             S20.2
3685 2017-01-18   09:56                             G40.9
9497 2017-02-16   09:52                             S83.6
2563 2017-01-12   20:47            M13.16, M25.56, M25.56
9731 2017-02-17   13:10            B99, B99, N39.0, N39.0
7759 2017-02-07   14:25                 R51, G43.0, G43.0
368  2017-01-02   15:05 T83.0, T83.0, T83.0, N13.3, N13.6
```

I want to aggregate this df in a special way. I want to count how many Numbers starting e.g. "A" on each day. I want a new dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Day          GroupA   GroupB   GroupC .....
1  2017-01-01       2        2       0    
2  2017-01-02       ..................
```

GroupA means Numbers starting with A. If there are multiple numbers starting with A in one single row it count be counted as one. The class of my number-column is character.

```
> class(df[1,3])
[1] "character"
> df[1,3]
[1] "A41.8, A41.51, A41.51"**
```

My problem is how I can combine the aggregate-command with the counts. My real df is a lot bigger, it is more than 2 years long, so I would need an automatized solution.

EDIT: See data down below

```
structure(list(Day= c("2017-01-07", "2017-01-23", "2017-01-08", 
"2017-01-13", "2017-02-10", "2017-01-07", "2017-01-24", "2017-01-02", 
"2017-01-03", "2017-01-06", "2017-01-11", "2017-01-21", "2017-01-13", 
"2017-01-10", "2017-02-18", "2017-01-10", "2017-01-31", "2017-01-27", 
"2017-01-23", "2017-01-13", "2017-02-10", "2017-01-09", "2017-01-23", 
"2017-01-09", "2017-01-08"), Time= c("02:02", "14:51", "02:12", 
"17:49", "00:00", "21:30", "22:28", "17:27", "12:14", "22:52", 
"14:19", "11:40", "19:33", "04:01", "15:59", "14:57", "08:34", 
"13:21", "02:01", "14:29", "20:17", "14:30", "02:34", "04:56", 
"14:34"), Number= c("H10.9", "K85.80, K85.20, K85.80, K85.20", 
"R09.1", "I10.90", "I48.9, I48.0, I48.9, I48.0", "A09.0, A09.0, R42, R42", 
"H16.1", "K92.1, K92.1, K92.1", "K40.90, J12.2, J18.0, J96.01, J12.2", 
"B99, J15.8, J18.0, J15.8", "S01.55", "M21.33", "I10.01, I10.01, J44.81, J44.81", 
"S00.95", "B08.2", "S05.1", "M20.1", "G40.2, S93.40, S93.40", 
"M25.51", "J44.19, J44.11, J44.19, J44.11", "G40.9, G40.2, G40.2", 
"E87.1, E87.1, J18.0, J18.0", "I10.91", "R22.0", "S06.5, S06.5, S06.5, R06.88, S12.22"
)), .Names = c("Day", "Time", "Number"), row.names = c(1336L, 
4687L, 1536L, 2737L, 8272L, 1507L, 4994L, 400L, 550L, 1305L, 
2325L, 4292L, 2748L, 2008L, 9974L, 2113L, 6144L, 5433L, 4577L, 
2697L, 8468L, 1883L, 4578L, 1783L, 1657L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput` so we can directly load into R?

Comment: See my edit, I added it to my question.

Comment: Another problem: there's only 1 day included here, so answers won't be particularly robust, and the aggregated output will only have 1 row. Maybe you can take a random sample across several days and include that instead?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that makes sense! Look on my edit please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty interesting problem that takes a little digging into. The first thing to do is get all the unique capital letters in each set in `Number` per row. `stringr::str_extract_all` gets you a list-column of string vectors that match this regex, and after taking unique values from each list entry, you have this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

as_tibble(df1) %>%
  mutate(Day = lubridate::ymd(Day),
         letters = purrr::map(stringr::str_extract_all(Number, "[A-Z]"), unique)) %>%
  select(-Number) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   Day        Time  letters  
#>   <date>     <chr> <list>   
#> 1 2017-01-07 02:02 <chr [1]>
#> 2 2017-01-23 14:51 <chr [1]>
#> 3 2017-01-08 02:12 <chr [1]>
#> 4 2017-01-13 17:49 <chr [1]>
#> 5 2017-02-10 00:00 <chr [1]>
#> 6 2017-01-07 21:30 <chr [2]>
```

Unnest it so you have one row per date & time per letter, then count the number of observations of each letter per day—gets confusing, and the order matters here. Then reshape it into a wide format so each group gets a column.

```r
as_tibble(df1) %>%
  mutate(Day = lubridate::ymd(Day),
         letters = purrr::map(stringr::str_extract_all(Number, "[A-Z]"), unique)) %>%
  select(-Number) %>%
  unnest(letters) %>%
  count(Day, letters) %>%
  arrange(letters) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = letters, names_prefix = "group", 
              values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 12
#>   Day        groupA groupB groupE groupG groupH groupI groupJ groupK groupM
#>   <date>      <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#> 1 2017-01-07      1      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
#> 2 2017-01-06      0      1      0      0      0      0      1      0      0
#> 3 2017-02-18      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
#> 4 2017-01-09      0      0      1      0      0      0      1      0      0
#> 5 2017-01-27      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0
#> 6 2017-02-10      0      0      0      1      0      1      0      0      0
#> # … with 2 more variables: groupR <int>, groupS <int>
```

In this first few rows with the sample of data, there aren't any 2s, but there are some later on in the data frame. (I don't yet understand how `pivot_wider` orders things, but you can arrange by day after this if you want.)